# ModelX() doesn't work with rotation in processing

Tags: graphics, 2d, processing

I want to follow the corner coordinates of a square after a push and popMatrix. I read somewhere I could use modelX, modelY to store the transformed coordinates in processing. However, it's working weird..

Here's some code. The square mode is CENTER.

```
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2); 
    translate(screenTransX, screenTransY);
    rotate(radians(screenRotation)); //this is controlled somewhere else
    rect(0,0, screenZ, screenZ);
    ULX = modelX(-screenZ/2, 0, 0);
    ULY = modelY(0,-screenZ/2, 0);
    //....omitted code for other corner coordinates
    popMatrix();

    //then I'm drawing the highlight points at the corners of the square
    ellipse(ULX,ULY,size,size);
    //...and other points
```

Here's the result:

[image]

It works very well with translation, and scaling up and down.

However, if I want to rotate, funny things happen:

[image]

The square is rotated slightly clockwise. The points somehow did not follow the corners. Instead, they got closer to the center.

If you keep rotating, the points just move back and forth on the diagonals of the original, unrotated square..

What should I do to track only the corners of the square?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can play with?